# Code work despite the interface is not implemented

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following code :

```
 interface ICalculator
 {
     int Sum ( int x,  int y);
 }

 abstract class AbsCalculator
 {
     public abstract int Sum(int x, int y);
 }

 class Calculator : AbsCalculator, ICalculator
 {
     public override int Sum(int x, int y)
     {
         Console.WriteLine ( "From overriden method" );
         return x + y;
     }
 }
```

The following statements works fine and the program compile despite i didn't implement the interface :

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
Console.WriteLine ( calculator.Sum(10, 20) );
```

So my first question is : Why did it work ?

Then, i add the following interface implementation to Calculator class :

```
int ICalculator.Sum(int x, int y)
{
     Console.WriteLine("From implemented method");
     return x + y;
}
```

When trying again the following statement :

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
Console.WriteLine ( calculator.Sum(10, 20) );
```

The method overriden from the abstract still called.
So my second question is : Why did the program call the method from the abstract class and not the method from the interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to implement interfaces in C#, either explicit or implicit but CLR has only one type of implementation - the explicit one.

When C# compiler sees that a class must implement an interface, it looks for methods matching the signatures of required classes by that interface and instructs CLR that those are implementations, to save you code.

So, in your case, When C# compiler sees that your class implements ICalculator, it will look for a public method which matches signature of Sum(int, int) and will consider that method the implementation. The fact that that method is overriden is not important.

If you want to give another meaning to the implementation of the method, you should give it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

No, you *are* impelementing it!  Your first block of code is perfectly legal. The name and signature matches what the interface requires: `int Sum(int x, int y)`.

Now, a signature like `int ICalculator.Sum(int x, int y)` is called [*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx), which means you can *only* access that method via a reference of the interface type.

```
interface ICalculator {
    int Sum ( int x,  int y);
}

abstract class AbsCalculator {
    public abstract int Sum(int x, int y);
}

class Calculator : AbsCalculator, ICalculator {
    public override int Sum(int x, int y) {
        Console.WriteLine ( "From overriden method" );
        return x + y;
    }

    int ICalculator.Sum(int x, int y) {
         Console.WriteLine("From explicitly implemented interface method");
         return x + y;
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        ICalculator icalc = calculator;

        // These calls will print different messages.
        calculator.Sum(10,20);
        icalc.Sum(10,20);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan Reinhart the method is overriden.I used the 'override' modifier.

Comment: Do you know what `override` means?

Comment: @Jonathan Reinhart Overriding a method is providing another implementation in a derived class.The method must be declared as virtual or abstract in the base class.

Comment: Right, so what is your point? Whether or not the function is `virtual`/`abstract` in a base class and overridden in the child class doesn't matter. The class is still implementing the interface as it needs to.

Comment: In other words, `ICalculator ic = new Calculator();  ic.Sum(1,2);` is going to work just fine, because `Calculator` has a `Sum` method that matches the required signature.

Comment: @Jonathan Reinhart In my first example, i didn't implement the interface method.I implemented it in the second example.

Comment: I understand that. But it doesn't matter! Do you understand my point? You **do have** the function with the correct signature in your `Calculator` class. Therefore you **are implementing** the interface. There's nothing complicated or fancy going on here.

Comment: @Jonathan: "you can only access that method via a reference of the interface type" awesome.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think that you didn't understand my point.All what you said about explicit interface implementation and casting to interface i know it and i understand it.But using the override keyword tell the compiler that we are overriding the method from the abstract class.The interface in the first example is not implemented and it must normally be, like you did to get the program compiled.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer for your first Qusetion**

In .NET When ever a type(Class) is loaded the CLR creates a method table and this table contains entries for the methods defined by the class and the methods inherited by the class so in your case The `Calculator` class contains the following entries

1. By default every class implicitly inherited from `Object` base class so the method table contains the entries for each virtual instance methods defined by the `Object` class.
2. Your class is inheriting from `AbsCalculator` abstract class so the method table defines an entry for the abstract class method `Sum`
3. Your class is inheriting the `ICalculator` interface so the method table defines an entry for the interface `Sum` method.

Here the C# compiler make an assumption that you are implementing the interface method because the method is `Public` and the signature of the interface method and abstract class method is same. so the compiler didn't give any error

**Answer for your Second Question**

While Implementing there are two concepts `Implicit Interface Method Implementation` and `Explicit Interface Method Implementation`

In `Implicit Interface Method Implementation` we are calling the interface methods with interface reference like as shown in below

```
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    ICalculator icalc = calculator;

    calculator.Sum(5,5);
    icalc.Sum(5,10);
```

In `Explicit Interface Method Implementation` when you prefix the name of the method with the name of the interface then it becomes explicit method implementation.

```
interface ICalc
{
    int Sum(int x, int y);
}

abstract class AbsCalc
{
    public abstract int Sum(int x, int y);
}

class Program : AbsCalc, ICalc
{
    public override int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From abstract Override");
        return x + y;
    }

    int ICalc.Sum(int x,int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From Intrface");
        return x + y;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Sum(1, 2);

        ICalc i = p;
        i.Sum(1,2);
    }
}
```